# How to read absolute path of files copied in to clipboard Linux and MacOS?

Tags: python, linux, macos

With the code below I'm able to enumerate the clipboard contents. Then based on clipboard format perform the desired action based on clipboard contents. This works with Windows OS however I'm not sure how to implement it on Linux/MacOS.

`xclip` seems to be the most well supported option Linux.

`xclip -o -t TARGETS` exposes the clip board mime types. However I'm not seeing the equivalent to `win32clipboard.CF_HDROP` to retrieve absolute path of files copied in to clipboard.

```py
def get_clipboard_formats():
    '''
    Return list of all data formats currently in the clipboard
    '''
    formats = []
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        import win32clipboard  # pylint: disable=import-error
        f = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(0)
        while f:
            formats.append(f)
            f = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(f)
        return formats
    else:
        print("get_clipboard_formats: Not implemented for OS")


def get_selected_files(folders=False):
    '''
    Copy selected (text or file is subsequently of interest) to a fresh clipboard
    '''
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        cb = Clipboard(from_system=True)
        cb.clear_clipboard()
        Key("c-c").execute()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        files = get_clipboard_files(folders)
        cb.copy_to_system()
        return files
    else:
        print("get_selected_files: Not implemented for OS")


def get_clipboard_files(folders=False):
    '''
    Enumerate clipboard content and return files either directly copied or
    highlighted path copied
    '''
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        import win32clipboard  # pylint: disable=import-error
        files = None
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        f = get_clipboard_formats()
        if win32clipboard.CF_HDROP in f:
            files = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_HDROP)
        elif win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT in f:
            files = [win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)]
        elif win32clipboard.CF_TEXT in f:
            files = [win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)]
        elif win32clipboard.CF_OEMTEXT in f:
            files = [win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_OEMTEXT)]
        if folders:
            files = [f for f in files if os.path.isdir(f)] if files else None
        else:
            files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(f)] if files else None
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        return files
    else:
        print("get_clipboard_files: Not implemented for OS")
```

**Edit**: Here's some work I've done for Linux with xclip .

- `get_clipboard_formats` uses xclip to grab the available formats contents of the clipboard.
- `enum_files_from_clipboard` clipboard contents that processes begins with `file://` or generic lines of output. Then generates a list by processing into unverified absolute file/folder paths.
- `get_clipboard_files` calls `enum_files_from_clipboard` based on available contents clipboard mime. Then validates file/folder paths effectively emulating `win32clipboard.CF_HDROP`

The function can be called with `get_clipboard_files(folders=False)` or `true`. Then make sure to have files/folders in the clipboard.

I acknowledge it could be a bit cleaner but for clarity sake as is.

```
from locale import getpreferredencoding
import sys, os, subprocess
from six import binary_type
try:
    from urllib import unquote
except ImportError:
    from urllib.parse import unquote

def get_clipboard_formats():
    '''
    Return list of all data formats currently in the clipboard
    '''
    formats = []
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        encoding = getpreferredencoding()
        com = ["xclip", "-o", "-t", "TARGETS"]
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(com,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                )
            for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                if isinstance(line, binary_type):
                    line = line.decode(encoding)
                    formats.append(line.strip())
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception from starting subprocess {0}: " "{1}".format(com, e))

    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        import win32clipboard  # pylint: disable=import-error
        f = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(0)
        while f:
            formats.append(f)
            f = win32clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(f)    

    if not formats:
        print("get_clipboard_formats: formats are {}: Not implemented".format(formats))
    else:
        #print(formats)
        return formats

def enum_files_from_clipboard(mime):
    '''
    Generates absolute paths from clipboard 
    Returns unverified absolute file/dir paths based on defined mime type
    '''
    paths = []
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        encoding = getpreferredencoding()
        com = ["xclip", "-selection", "clipboard","-o", mime]
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(com,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                )
            for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
                if isinstance(line, binary_type):
                    line = line.decode(encoding).strip()
                    if line.startswith("file://"):
                        paths.append(unquote(line.replace("file://", "")))
                    else:
                        paths.append(unquote(line)) # Will append line which will be checked against isfile\isdir
            #print(paths)
            return paths
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception from starting subprocess {0}: " "{1}".format(com, e))

def get_clipboard_files(folders=False):
    '''
    Enumerate clipboard content and return files/folders either directly copied or
    highlighted path copied
    '''
    files = None
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        import win32clipboard  # pylint: disable=import-error
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        f = get_clipboard_formats()
        if win32clipboard.CF_HDROP in f:
            files = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_HDROP)
        elif win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT in f:
            files = [win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_UNICODETEXT)]
        elif win32clipboard.CF_TEXT in f:
            files = [win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)]
        elif win32clipboard.CF_OEMTEXT in f:
            files = [win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32clipboard.CF_OEMTEXT)]
        if folders:
            files = [f for f in files if os.path.isdir(f)] if files else None
        else:
            files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(f)] if files else None
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
        print(files)
        return files

    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
        f = get_clipboard_formats()
        if "UTF8_STRING" in f:
            files = enum_files_from_clipboard("UTF8_STRING")
        elif "TEXT" in f:
            files = enum_files_from_clipboard("TEXT")
        elif "text/plain" in f:
            files = enum_files_from_clipboard("text/plain")
        if folders:
            files = [f for f in files if os.path.isdir(str(f))] if files else None
        else:
            files = [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(str(f))] if files else None
        print(files)
        return files

#get_clipboard_files(folders=True)
```